# Trigger to Insert, Update, Delete Stock Qty in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables as Figure below:
[image: Table Figure]

My scenario is when there is insert, update or delete tblGRDetail, then it's update StockQty field in tblSPStock.

Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[StockUpdate] on [dbo].[tblGRDetail]
FOR INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted INNER JOIN tblGR ON inserted.GRNo=tblGR.GRNo WHERE tblGR.DealerCode=(SELECT DealerCode FROM tblSPStock WHERE DealerCode=tblGR.DealerCode) AND inserted.PartCode=(Select PartCode from tblSPStock WHERE PartCode=inserted.PartCode)) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted INNER JOIN tblGR ON deleted.GRNo=tblGR.GRNo WHERE tblGR.DealerCode=(SELECT DealerCode FROM tblSPStock WHERE DealerCode=tblGR.DealerCode) AND deleted.PartCode=(Select PartCode from tblSPStock WHERE PartCode=deleted.PartCode))
BEGIN
UPDATE tblSPStock
SET StockQty=StockQty-(Select GRQty From deleted INNER JOIN tblGR ON deleted.GRNo=tblGR.GRNo WHERE tblSPStock.DealerCode=tblgr.DealerCode AND tblSPStock.PartCode=deleted.PartCode)+(Select GRQty From inserted INNER JOIN tblGR ON inserted.GRNo=tblGR.GRNo WHERE tblSPStock.DealerCode=tblGR.DealerCode AND tblSPStock.PartCode=inserted.PartCode)
WHERE tblSPStock.DealerCode=(select DealerCode from inserted INNER JOIN tblGR ON inserted.GRNo=tblgr.GRNo)
AND tblSPStock.PartCode=(select PartCode from inserted)
AND tblspstock.PartCode=(select PartCode from deleted)
END

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted INNER JOIN tblGR ON inserted.GRNo=tblGR.GRNo WHERE tblGR.DealerCode=(SELECT DealerCode FROM tblSPStock WHERE DealerCode=tblGR.DealerCode) AND inserted.PartCode=(Select PartCode from tblSPStock WHERE PartCode=inserted.PartCode)) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted INNER JOIN tblGR ON deleted.GRNo=tblGR.GRNo WHERE tblGR.DealerCode=(SELECT DealerCode FROM tblSPStock WHERE DealerCode=tblGR.DealerCode) AND deleted.PartCode=(Select PartCode from tblSPStock WHERE PartCode=deleted.PartCode))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tblSPStock (PartCode,
                        StockQty,
                        DealerCode)
SELECT PartCode, GRQty, tblGR.DealerCode from inserted inner join tblGR on inserted.GRNo=tblgr.GRNo
END

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted INNER JOIN tblGR ON inserted.GRNo=tblGR.GRNo WHERE tblGR.DealerCode=(SELECT DealerCode FROM tblSPStock WHERE DealerCode=tblGR.DealerCode) AND inserted.PartCode=(Select PartCode from tblSPStock WHERE PartCode=inserted.PartCode)) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted INNER JOIN tblGR ON deleted.GRNo=tblGR.GRNo WHERE tblGR.DealerCode=(SELECT DealerCode FROM tblSPStock WHERE DealerCode=tblGR.DealerCode) AND deleted.PartCode=(Select PartCode from tblSPStock WHERE PartCode=deleted.PartCode))
BEGIN
UPDATE tblSPStock
SET StockQty=StockQty-(Select GRQty From deleted)
WHERE tblSPStock.DealerCode=(select DealerCode from deleted INNER JOIN tblGR ON deleted.GRNo=tblgr.GRNo)
AND tblspstock.PartCode=(select partcode from deleted)
END
END
```

When i insert into tblGRDetail it showed error below:
**Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery foolows=, !=, <, <=,>,>= or whenthe subquery is ude as an epression**

Any one here have any idea to this error pls!

**==UPDATED==**

Now i use MERGE in my trigger, but when i delete tblGRDetail it's not update StockQty.
but if i remove INNER JOIN tblGR g ON d.GRNo=g.GRNo, it's OK.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[DeleteStock] on [dbo].[tblGRDetail]
FOR DELETE, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    MERGE tblSPStock
    Using (
        SELECT
            d.PartCode,
            d.GRQty,
            g.DealerCode
        FROM deleted d INNER JOIN tblGR g ON d.GRNo=g.GRNo
    ) MergeData ON tblSPStock.PartCode= MergeData.PartCode
                   AND tblSPStock.DealerCode=MergeData.DealerCode
         WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET
        tblSPStock.StockQty=tblSPStock.StockQty-MergeData.GRQty;
END
```

for insert, update is ok, problem only delete.

Pls. your help is appropriated.

Comment: Is `StockNo` used elsewhere in your system? Because it strikes me that the remaining columns in `tblSPStock` can just be derived from the other two tables and so you may as well have it be an indexed view rather than a real table. SQL Server will then take care of maintaining the correct total automatically. Even if you do need `StockNo` and so do need a table, you might still consider putting this stock total into an indexed view instead, for again the reason that SQL Server will maintain it automatically.

Comment: Actually, i need only PartCode+DealerCode is unique and it's StockQty in tblSPStock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to switch to using an indexed view, for whatever reason, I think that the following is appropriate:

```
create trigger tblGRDetail_T_IUD on tblGRDetail
after insert,update,delete
as
    ;With Updates as (
        select
            COALESCE(i.PartCode,d.PartCode) as PartCode,
            DealerCode,
            COALESCE(i.GRQty,0) - COALESCE(d.GRQty,0) as Qty
        from
            (select PartCode,GRNo,SUM(GRQty) as GRQty from inserted
                   group by PartCode,GRNo) i
                full outer join
            (select PartCode,GRNo,SUM(GRQty) as GRQty from deleted
                   group by PartCode,GRNo) d
                on
                    i.PartCode = d.PartCode and
                    i.GRNo = d.GRNo
                inner join
            tblGR g
                on
                    g.GRNo = COALESCE(i.GRNo,d.GRNo)
    )
    update s
    set StockQty = StockQty + u.Qty
    from
        tblSPStock s
            inner join
        Updates u
            on
                s.PartCode = u.PartCode and
                s.DealerCode = u.DealerCode
```

If `GRNo` and `PartCode`, taken together, are actually unique in `tblGRDetail` then you can take out the inner subqueries that perform `GROUP`ing on `inserted` and `deleted`.

Comment: Thanks Damiem_The_Unbeliever, anyway after tested to add new data in tblGRDetail, there is no data in tblSPStock. checked in your trigger there is no insert but only update transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Hae you tried - ah - understanding the very clear error message?

Here is a hint for you - triggers are not "per row", they are per operation.

For example:

> SET StockQty=StockQty-(Select GRQty From deleted)

What happens when deleted has more than one row because the update was for more than one line?  Not legal like this. Assume you have multiple lines in both inserted and deleted.

Comment: sure i have multiple lines data per operation. so how to fix to avoid this error, Pls. i am a new starter for trigger.

Comment: THat is not trigger. That is basic SQL. Rewrite the SQL to avoid the error.